# display fixed div within relative div with percentage offset [SAFARI bug]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I have a problem working with Bootstrap and Safari.

I want to place a fixed div relative to it´s parent and it works in all browsers except Safari.

The same problem is explained here:
https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/147

Now i try to find a good workaround:

Original Code (does not work in Safari)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
      <div class="fixed-div">SOME FIXED CONTENT</div>
      CONTENT A
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
      CONTENT B
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fixed-div{
   position:fixed;
}
```

this does not work as expected in Safari. The "fixed-div" is not "pushed" like it`s parent. It should be displayed above "CONTENT A".

**I found a solution but i think this is not a clean one:**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="fixed-div">SOME FIXED CONTENT</div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>

   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
      CONTENT A
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
      CONTENT B
   </div>
</div>
```

**Do you have some better ideas how to fix this?**

Comment: Fixed divs are fixed in relation to the viewport, I think you want absolute not fixed.

Comment: not really i want it fixed (also when scrolling) but starting at the same position as the parent div. It works in all browsers except Safari.

Safari behaves "as expected" when you do not have "col-XX-push-YY" (Safari ignores the percentage offset on the left)

Answer (score -1):

Try switching to the CSS property from `fixed` to `absolute`. If that does not fix your issue you could add custom check before within your HTML to see what browser a user is coming from and load that specific CSS page [How to use different CSS for Different Browsers](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml).

Comment: Thanks for your respond.

But position absolute does not fit my needs because i want it fixed also when scrolling.

Using different css does also not work because i did not find any css which will work on safari to get the expected results.

Comment: I just ran your the link you provided to the Github issue's jsfiddle in Safari.

Have you tried to adjust the z-index for the `.fixed-div` ?